# Suppress page header after group footer

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to suppress the page header that appears *after* the group footer and *before* the new Report footer. I have tried `pagenumber = totalpagecount` but it only suppresses it on the last page.

How can I suppress the page header specifically after the group footer ends?

Comment: I agree the page header appears before the group header. My report is in below format:
Report Header,
Page Header,
Group Header,
Details Sections,
Group Footer,
Report Footer

I don't want the page header to be repeated once the Report Footer section is started. I have tried using formula pagenumber = totalpagecount in the page header. But because of this only last page doesn't contain page header. Can you suggest any way to suppress the header once the Report Footer section is started.

Comment: I want to suppress page header once the Report footer Section is started.

Comment: If i will use this  formula pagenumber <> 1 then it will suppress header starting from page 2
Example: In my case, If the data present till group footer is displayed on 3 pages then page header should only be displayed till 3 pages. On next page (4 page) there should not be any page header and only data available in  report footer should  be displayed .